# Chain Akka Streams Kafka with Akka-http by Source[Bytestring]

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http, reactive-kafka, akka-kafka

I'm receiving a file as a Bytestring from Kafka Reactive Streams consumer, which I want to send to a service.

Is there a away to extract Source[Bytestring, Any] from Kafka Reactive Stream Consumer, so that I can chain the stream from Kafka to Akka-http, without loading an entire Bytestring in memory and then doing an akka-http request?

Comment: If you have the ByteString as a case class field then it's already in memory...

Comment: Is there any other pattern I can use to send ByteString without a case class. I need case class because it also contains other information. Can I have Source[ByteString] as a case class field? would it even make sense? and how se/derialisaiton would work

Comment: Yes, it is probably possible. I guess you need to share at least your current solution for anyone to suggest improvements :)